# Использование ключ. слова "ts" для подсветки TypeScript кода

Tags: дефект, подсветка-синтаксиса

При использовании ключ. слова `typescript` для подсветки TypeScript кода, подсветка работает правильно, вот пример:

```typescript
enum Greeting {
  English = 'Hello',
  Russian = 'Здравствуйте'
}

const greeting: Greeting = Greeting.English
```

Но если использовать сокращение в виде `ts`, то подсветка уже работает криво:

```
enum Greeting {
  English = 'Hello',
  Russian = 'Здравствуйте'
}

const greeting: Greeting = Greeting.English
```

При этом для JavaScript это не релевантно, там можно использовать как `javascript`:

```javascript
const Greeting = {
  English: 'Hello',
  Russian: 'Здравствуйте'
}

const greeting = Greeting.English
```

Так и `js`:

```js
const Greeting = {
  English: 'Hello',
  Russian: 'Здравствуйте'
}

const greeting = Greeting.English
```

Я считаю что сокращение должно существовать и для TypeScript.